# Sort items in ng-repeat is falling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets

I have the following piece of code that listen on an `socket.io` event and adds items to a scope array if they not exist already in the array:

```
socketIOService.on('news arrived', function(data){
    var newlyArrived = _.filter(data, function (item){
      if(_.findWhere($scope.listOfNews, { hash: item.hash})){
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });


    $scope.listOfNews = _.uniq($scope.listOfNews.concat(newlyArrived), 'hash');
    $scope.$digest();
  });
```

And I have a `ng-repeat` inside which I want to sort my items.

`ng-repeat="item in listOfNews | orderBy:'title':true as results track by $index"`

The problem is that the items on the dom are **partialy** sorted. I am thinking that probably this is related to the `socket.io`and the time that some items are pushed to the `$scope.listofNews`. Am I right? Any idea why this is happening and how can I solve it?

**Update to make things clear:**

1. It doesnt matter if I sort by title, date, or any attributed. The results are always partially and not fully sorted.
2. There is no difference if I use `$apply()` or `$digest` or `$evalAsync()`

Comment: Have you tried using `$apply()` instead of `$digest()`? The docs say it usually shouldn't be called and `$apply()` should be preferred

Comment: @XrXrXr  `$apply()` triggers a `$digest` at the end of the cycle. You are right, but its not related to the question.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for us?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- it is a socket.io service/backend that I run locally, so its a bit time consuming to create a fiddle. But maybe I will do it if there is no answer soon.

Comment: Some questions: 1 - You're calling this function inside your `$scope`? 2 - The property used to sort has special chars/diacritics?

Comment: Also, remove that `as results track by $index`, there's is no need of it, its redundant. And, skip that `$scope.$digest()` call, use `$scope.$evalAsync()` instead: it don't conflict with the current `$digest` running.

Comment: @MateusDuartePoncedeLeon 1. It doesnt matter if I sort by `title` or `date` or anything else, the results are **partially** and not fully sorted. 2. I want the `as results` to have the number of filtered results `results.length` after I apply a filter.